# Problem with wp_insert_post()

Tags: posts, loop, api

When you create posts programatically with `wp_insert_post()`, these posts don't display correctly in the loop when you click the post navigation 'previous posts'. It misses some posts out and shows some of the same posts again. There are no problems if the posts are created in the admin panel in `admin > posts > add new`. Also, the posts created with `wp_insert_post()` display correctly if there is no post navigation and you show all the posts on one page. So there is something not working right with `wp_insert_post()` that is preventing the posts from displaying correctly with post navigation.

To recreate this issue -

Create several posts programatically like this:

```
<?php
add_action('init', 'hps_insert_posts');
function hps_insert_posts() {

    if( null == get_page_by_title( 'Test Post 1', OBJECT, 'post' ) ) {
        wp_insert_post( 
            array(
              'post_title'    => 'Test Post 1',
              'post_name'     => 'test-post-1',
              'post_status'   => 'publish',
              'post_type'     => 'post',
              'post_author'   => 1
            )
        );
    }

    if( null == get_page_by_title( 'Test Post 2', OBJECT, 'post' ) ) {
        wp_insert_post( 
            array(
              'post_title'    => 'Test Post 2',
              'post_name'     => 'test-post-2',
              'post_status'   => 'publish',
              'post_type'     => 'post',
              'post_author'   => 1
            )
        );
    }

    if( null == get_page_by_title( 'Test Post 3', OBJECT, 'post' ) ) {
        wp_insert_post( 
            array(
              'post_title'    => 'Test Post 3',
              'post_name'     => 'test-post-3',
              'post_status'   => 'publish',
              'post_type'     => 'post',
              'post_author'   => 1
            )
        );
    }

    if( null == get_page_by_title( 'Test Post 4', OBJECT, 'post' ) ) {
        wp_insert_post( 
            array(
              'post_title'    => 'Test Post 4',
              'post_name'     => 'test-post-4',
              'post_status'   => 'publish',
              'post_type'     => 'post',
              'post_author'   => 1
            )
        );
    }

    if( null == get_page_by_title( 'Test Post 5', OBJECT, 'post' ) ) {
        wp_insert_post( 
            array(
              'post_title'    => 'Test Post 5',
              'post_name'     => 'test-post-5',
              'post_status'   => 'publish',
              'post_type'     => 'post',
              'post_author'   => 1
            )
        );
    }
}
```

After running this code, check the results in `Admin > Posts` and you'll see all these posts have been created in order, they should be exactly the same as if you created several posts using `admin > post > add new` and just adding a title.

Then create several posts using the admin panel in `Admin > Posts > Add new`.

So you've now got several posts created programatically and several posts created in `admin > posts > add new`

Go to `admin > reading` and set:
Blog pages show at most = 1
Front page displays = your latest posts

then just use any theme, or just create a really basic loop in index.php with just the post title and post nav like:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php the_posts_navigation(); ?>

<?php else : ?>

    <p>No posts available</p>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Then just keep clicking the previous posts button to show every post one by one. You'll see that all the posts created in the admin panel will show correctly, and any posts created programatically with `wp_insert_post()` will have some missing, or it will show the same post again.

Any help appreciated with this problem.

Comment: Which plugins are right now activate on your system ? Check them deactivating one by one. Also check replacing the `functions.php` by themes default `functions.php`. If then it's not worked please try with a fresh installation of `WordPress`. Cause I tried on my system it worked perfectly fine.

Comment: Got to agree with @the_dramatist I double checked the parameters and return values of your function calls and can't see anything out of place in that code.

Comment: It seems perfectly fine. First it shows the admin created posts on descending order and then it shows the Test Posts descending order. I don't think there is any problem.